# SQL query not in return specific result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to create query to not include the cars where the part_id = '1'. This works, but the car continues to show up because the car_id is associated with multiple other part_id's.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    distinct car.car_id, 
             part.description
FROM car
JOIN car_parts part on (car.car_id = part.car_id)
WHERE part.part_id <> '1'
```

My table: car_parts

```
Car ID | Part ID
   1        1
   1        3
   1        4
   2        2
   2        5
   2        7
   3        1
   3        4
   3        9
   4        1
```

The only car_id that should be returned from the query is car_id = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct car.car_id, part.description
FROM car
JOIN car_parts part on (car.car_id = part.car_id)
WHERE part.part_id <> '1'
AND car.car_id not in ( select car_id from part where part = 1 )
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no super efficient solutions to this, but this answer is probably the best you will get. Although I suggest you change "select car_id from part ..." to "select distinct car_id from part ...". The distinct should make your exclude list a bit shorter.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson if there's a `KEY {Car_id, Part_ID}` then adding distinct would only make it slower

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure about that, it is something he would have to bench mark. Also you can remove the first where condition (it will be satisfied by the second condition automatically)

Comment: It is kinda slow, but it works, and that's all I need it to do at the moment. Thanks!